# how to reduce user priority field on MySQL when left joining 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Let's say I have `emails` and `priority` table:

priority table fields:

```
Fields: uid, priority
```

emails table fields:

```
Fields: id, uid, content
```

Each user has many emails. In a script I fetch user's emails based on their priority (By joining 2 tables). But problem rises when I I fetch in batch and a user with highest priority has 1000 mail in queue. The second user has the priority of 99. I should send at most 2 emails of that user with the highest priority, because on the third record of first user his priority will 97 and lower than the second user.

How to solve this problem? I'm programming in `PHP` so if the solution is better resolved in `PHP` tell me how.

This is the main query:

```
select * from emails e left join by priority p on e.uid=p.uid order by priority DESC
```

---

**EDIT1:**
Data in emails table:

```
id     uid     email_content

1      321     some example data
2      434     some other example data
3      321     another from first user
4      321     again another from 321
```

And data in priority table is as below:

```
id      uid      priority

1       321      100
2       434      99
```

User with `uid` equal to 321 has the highest priority at first, but not for all of his emails. When first email is sent priority should be 99 and after the second email priority would be equal to 98. Now the third email should not be sent and email of user with uid of 434 has the highest priority.

As I have fetched 10 records already the updated priority is not fetched!

Comment: Please post the query and some sample data of each table

Comment: show sample data's in table structure and output

Comment: @Noman, please see the edit part for the query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just simple fetch one User. Send EMail and then just update the priority.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root","", "stackoverflow");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


$query = "SELECT e.id, email_content,p.uid from emails e INNER JOIN priority p ON e.uid=p.uid ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1";


$updateQuery = "UPDATE priority SET priority = priority - 1 WHERE uid = ?";

while (true) {
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        break;
    }
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    // @TODO send the mail
    // delete the email entry
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM emails WHERE id = $row[0]");
    // NOW update the PRIORITY
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE priority SET priority = priority - 1 WHERE uid = $row[2]");
}
```